# Stupid numbers game

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Occasionally I encounter a recurring instance of stupidity when I teach mathematics, namely that someone asks if we can play a game known in Danish under the name "bum", since that person thinks that that game has something relevant to do with mathematics.

The game goes as follows

> You have to decide on a decimal digit $a$. Then people in the room count through the natural numbers taking turns, each person shouting out one number then passing on to the next person. But whenever the number to shout is divisible by $a$ or has the digit $a$ somewhere in it, that person shouts "bum" instead.

Today I answered to the suggestion of playing that game using $a=7$ by saying, that I found the game of no mathematical relevance. But if we were to make anything mathematically interesting of it, we should instead find out how many times the word "bum" is shouted in a flawless "bum"-game running from $1$ through $10^6$.

I estimated this figure as $10^6-9^6\cdot \frac 67=544479.\overline{142857}$. Later I wrote a code snippet working out the exact answer as $544480$.

### Question

Is there a nice way to derive the figure $544480$ mathematically without writing a program?

Comment: Your estimate appears very close

Comment: @qwr: Yes, I was quite pleased to see how close it was. But I have no mathematical argument as to why it should be accurate. I estimated it to be good within $\pm 2$ by mere gut feeling even before I coded. But intuition and mathematical truths do not always coincide ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $6$ digits, each of which must be in $[0,9]\setminus\{7\}$. The remainders modulo $7$ of the digit values $10^k$ for $k\in[0,5]$ are $1,3,2,6,4,5$, respectively, which are all invertible in $\mathbb Z_7$. Group the admissible digits as $[0,6]\cup\{8,9\}$. If any of the digits is in $[0,6]$, as the first such digit varies across $[0,6]$ the remainder of the number modulo $7$ also varies across $[0,6]$, so exactly $1/7$ of such numbers are bummers. That leaves only the $2^6=64$ numbers consisting only of $8$s and $9$s, equivalent to $1$s and $2$s. Since the sum of the digit values is a multiple of $7$, this is equivalent to $0$ and $1$s. So the remaining question is how many subsets of $[1,6]$ add up to $0$ modulo $7$. We don't have to test all $64$ since a subset adds up to $0$ if and only if its complement does. The subsets with less than $3$ elements are easy to find: only $\{\}$, $\{1,6\}$, $\{2,5\}$, $\{3,4\}$ add up to $0$. Of the ones with $3$ elements, we only need to check the ones containing $1$, and a moment's reflection shows that of these, only $\{1,2,4\}$ qualifies. That yields a total of $2(1+3+1)=10$ out of $64$ subsets that add up to $0$, so the total number of bummers is $10^6-\frac67(9^6-64)-64+10=544480$.

This also throws some light on why your estimate was so good – it was only the extra $64$ numbers for which your estimate $64/7\simeq9.1$ was off by about $1$.

Comment: Brilliant! That really sheds light on what happens in a very neat way!

Comment: BTW: I was extremely lucky that the number in question was $a=7$. For $a=2,3,...,9$ the error of my estimate formula $bummers=10^6-9^6\cdot (a-1)/a$ is off by $29524.5$, $0$, $14762.25$, $47239.2$, $9841.5$, $-0.8571$, $7381.125$ and $0$ respectively. So my gut feeling was essentially wrong. I thought those errors would be lesser due to some kind of symmetry, which $a=7$ has as you pointed out, but other values of $a$ do not have.

Comment: @String: Well, there are two $0$s in there (for the divisors of the base minus $1$, I guess) -- so your luck wasn't actually that extreme -- you had a $3/8$ chance to hit a lucky number. (BTW, I only know the game with $a=7$.)

Comment: Right, but still my intuition was wrong. I thought none of those figures would have an error greater than, say, $10$ or so.